# json parse error with double quotes

Tags: php, javascript, json, parsing, double-quotes

A double quote even if escaped is throwing parse error.
look at the code below

```
//parse the json in javascript  
var testJson = '{"result": ["lunch", "\"Show\""] }';  
var tags = JSON.parse(testJson);  
alert (tags.result[1]);
```

This is throwing parse error because of the double quotes (which are already escaped).
Even `eval()` won't work here.
But if i escape it with double slashes like this:

```
var result = '{"result": ["lunch", "\\"Show\\""] }';  
var tags = JSON.parse(result);  
alert (tags.result[1]);
```

then it works fine.
Why do we need to use double slash here in javascript?
The problem is that PHP `json_encode()` function escapes a double quote with a single slash (like this: `\"show\"`) which `JSON.parse` won't be able to parse. How do i handle this situation?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, finally, JSON's parse uses the same eval, so there's no difference when you give them smth. with incorrect syntax. In this case you have to escape correctly your quotes in php, and then escape them and their escaping slashes with json_encode

```
<?php
    $json = '{"result": ["lunch", "\"Show\""] }';
    echo json_encode($json);
?>

OUTPUT: "{\"result\": [\"lunch\", \"\\\"Show\\\"\"] }"
```

This should work on client-side JS (if I've made no typos).

Comment: But this is something which should be taken care of by the json_encode() function.
Why is it returning something which can not be correctly parsed by JSON.parse().

Comment: It's not a bug in json_encode (I'm assuming that's what you meant). json_encode is not intended to create JavaScript string literals, so it doesn't do the additional escaping.

Answer (score 36):

Javascript unescapes its strings and json unescapes them as well.
the first string ( `'{"result": ["lunch", "\"Show\""] }'` ) is seen by the json parser as
`{"result": ["lunch", ""Show""] }`, because `\"` in javascript means `"`, but doesn't exit the double quoted string.

The second string `'{"result": ["lunch", "\\\"Show\\\""] }'` gets first unescaped to `{"result": ["lunch", "\"Show\""] }` (and that is correctly unescaped by json).

I think, that `'{"result": ["lunch", "\\"Show\\""] }'` should work too.

Answer (score 11):

This problem is caused by the two-folded string escaping mechanism: one comes from JS and one comes from JSON.

A combination of the backslash character combined with another following character is used to represent **one character** that is not otherwise representable within the string.
''\\'' stands for '\' etc.

This escaping mechanism takes place before JSON.parse() works.

For Example,

```
var parsedObj = JSON.parse('{"sentence": "It is one backslash(\\\\)"}');
console.log(parsedObj.sentence);
>>>"It is one backslash(\)"
```

From the string generator's perspective, it **passes four backlashes** '\' into the JavaScript interpretor.

From the JavaScript interpretor's perspective, it inteprets **there are two backlashes**(\) as each '\\' sequence will be interpreted as one '\'.

From the JSON parser's perspective, it **receives two backlashes**(\\) and the JSON string escape rules will parses it as one single '\' which is the output result.

Explain you first code:

```
var testJson = '{"result": ["lunch", "\"Show\""] }';
//The real string after sequence escaping in to JS is
//'{"result": ["lunch", ""Show""] }' 
//which is passed into the JSON.parse.
//Thus, it breaks the JSON grammar and generates an error
var tags = JSON.parse(testJson);  
alert (tags.result[1]);
```

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](http://is.php.net/json_encode)

> `JSON_HEX_APOS`  (integer) All ' are converted to \u0027 
>   `JSON_HEX_QUOT` (integer) All " are converted to \u0022

json_encode() takes two args, the value and options. So try

```
json_encode($result, JSON_HEX_QUOT); // or
json_encode($result, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

I haven't tried this though.

Comment: You are using a version of PHP older than 5.3.0 then, as the docs indicate.

Comment: That is the answer, but it should have been the default behaviour to begin with

Answer (score 10):

## php to javascript Object (php >= 5.3.0)

```
var storesLocations = JSON.parse('<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($storesLocations,JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)) ?>');
```

Comment: This is also a very good workaround. It solved my problem.

Comment: This is a very nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off `magic_quotes_gpc` in **php.ini**.

Answer (score 0):

If the standard C escapes are added, then `JSON.parse` will convert sequences like `\"` into `"`, `\\` into `\`, `\n` into a line-feed, etc.

```
'foo\\bar\nbaz"' === JSON.parse('"foo\\\\bar\\nbaz\\""')
```

In our project's case:

original string `""{\"lat\":28.4594965,\"lng\":77.0266383}""`

After passing to `JSON.parse()`

```
"{"lat":28.4594965,"lng":77.0266383}"
```

On 2<sup>**nd**</sup> pass to `JSON.parse()`

```
{lat: 28.4594965, lng: 77.0266383}
```

Notice that `JSON.parse()` removed escaping characters instead of converting `string` to `object`.

After the escaping characters were removed, the string to object conversion worked.

Here is the demo:

```
while (typeof p1 != 'object') {
  p1 = JSON.parse(p1);
  pass++;
  console.log('On pass ', pass, p1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
<?php
$json = '{"result": ["lunch", "\"Show\""] }';
echo addslashes(json_encode($json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. and then try commented

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<pre><?php ($_POST)?print_r($_POST):'' ?></pre>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="time" name="time"><br>
    <input type="date" name="date"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id"><br>
    <textarea name="detail"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
<?php 
/* data */
$data = [
            'name'=>'vinay"'."'\\\\",
            'email'=>'imvsrajput@demo.demo',
            'time'=>date('H:i:00'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d'),
            'detail'=>'Try this var_dump(0=="ZERO") \\ \\"'." ' \\\\    ",
            'id'=>123,
        ];
?>
<span style="display: none;" class="ajax-data"><?=json_encode($data)?></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Error */
    // var json = JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($data)?>');
    /* Error solved */
    var json = JSON.parse($('.ajax-data').html());
    console.log(json)
    /* automatically assigned value by name attr */
    for(x in json){
        $('[name="'+x+'"]').val(json[x]);
    }
</script>
```