# special char in JSON

Tags: php, json, escaping

I should send `Hi"` to a Yahoo server, so in PHP I should place `\` befor the `"`, but it will get bad JSON arguments. How should I do it?

Place `Hi"` in JSON code without error?

```
$message = "Hi\"";
$postdata = '{
             "message" : "'.$message.'"
             }';
```

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949604/json-parse-error-with-double-quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) instead of hand-crafting JSON:

```
$postdata = json_encode(array("message" => $message));
```

If you must handcraft your JSON, don't forget to add a backslash before a quotation mark:

```
$message = "Hi\\\"";
// or, more clearly ...
$message = 'Hi\\"';
```

Comment: +1 on json_encode from me also. You really shouldn't be hand-coding your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

New line character will not work in case of Tooltip with some browsers.

Not working `\r\n` or `\n` 
Not working single quotes `\'abcd`

Use double backslash to escape characters.

**Solution :** use `'\\\r\\\n'` in place of `'\r\n'` , 
it will solve your problem. 
Happy coding...!