# HTML decoding issue with quotes

Tags: javascript, json, html-encode

I have an input hidden element, the value of which contains JSON of an HTML encoded string.
Something like

```
{"QuestionInstruction":"&lt;snippet lang=&quot;java&quot;&gt; public class Test() {\n\n}&lt;/snippet&gt;","QuestionDescription":"it this correct?","Choices":["True","False"] }
```

and when I do

```
var text = document.getElementById('inputId').value,
```

the &quot automatically gets converted to "". The value of `text` comes as -

```
{"QuestionInstruction":"&lt;snippet lang="java"&gt; public class Test() {\n\n}&lt;/snippet&gt;","QuestionDescription":"it this correct?","Choices":["True","False"] }
```

So, then JSON parsing fails. :(

I am using FF9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json parse error with double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949604/json-parse-error-with-double-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get around this by using the following function if I know to expect a value that could contain quotes when creating a JSON string/object...

```
function getJSONFriendlyString(text) {
    return text.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
}
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: please see my edited question and let know how your answer could be a solution

Comment: @saarthak: So how is the hidden input being set? why are only some quotes shown as `&quot;`? you may need to go to the code that creates the JSON string in the first place and try and resolve from there

Comment: Hey @musefan, I didn't do exactly like you said but did html encoding after preparing the JSON. and that worked. Thanks for hinting. :)