# json_decode + json_encode combo not creating original JSON

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON that I got through an API call, and I run `json_decode` on it, grab an array from it, then re-encode it with `json_encode`. The result however is not the same JSON; it's messing up with the URLs. How do I make it encode properly?

**original**

```
{"created_at":"Mon, 19 Mar 2012 01:34:41 +0000","entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"stanford","indices":[23,32]}],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Of4z6jKG","expanded_url":"http:\/\/360.io\/5sZc2T","display_url":"360.io\/5sZc2T","indices":[33,53]}],"user_mentions":[]},"from_user":"rayfk","from_user_id":335143881,"from_user_id_str":"335143881","from_user_name":"Raymond Kennedy","geo":{"coordinates":[37.4227,-122.1753],"type":"Point"},"id":181554251733020673,"id_str":"181554251733020673","iso_language_code":"en","metadata":{"result_type":"recent"},"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1468102095\/image_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1468102095\/image_normal.jpg","source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/www.occipital.com\/360\/app&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;360 Panorama&lt;\/a&gt;","text":"View from mid lake log #stanford http:\/\/t.co\/Of4z6jKG","to_user":null,"to_user_id":null,"to_user_id_str":null,"to_user_name":null}
```

**after decode/encode combo**

```
{"created_at":"Mon, 19 Mar 2012 01:34:41 +0000","entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"stanford","indices":[23,32]}],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Of4z6jKG","expanded_url":"http:\/\/360.io\/5sZc2T","display_url":"360.io\/5sZc2T","indices":[33,53]}],"user_mentions":[]},"from_user":"rayfk","from_user_id":335143881,"from_user_id_str":"335143881","from_user_name":"Raymond Kennedy","geo":{"coordinates":[37.4227,-122.1753],"type":"Point"},"id":181554251733020673,"id_str":"181554251733020673","iso_language_code":"en","metadata":{"result_type":"recent"},"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1468102095\/image_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1468102095\/image_normal.jpg","source":"<a href="http:\/\/www.occipital.com\/360\/app" rel="nofollow">360 Panorama<\/a>","text":"View from mid lake log #stanford http:\/\/t.co\/Of4z6jKG","to_user":null,"to_user_id":null,"to_user_id_str":null,"to_user_name":null}
```

Those are the full snippets, but the culprit is this:

**original** `"source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/www.occipital.com\/360\/app&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;360 Panorama&lt;\/a&gt;"`

**after** `"source":"<a href="http:\/\/www.occipital.com\/360\/app" rel="nofollow">360 Panorama<\/a>"`

Comment: What's "messed up" exactly? I can't spot the difference spontaneously.

Comment: added it just now; sorry about that

Comment: it might also not be malformed...i use this tool to look at JSON and it's saying it's a bad variable: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Those are HTML entities that `json_encode` should not touch at all. Sure you're not putting that strings through `htmlentities` or similar?

Comment: did you used `htmlentities()`?

Comment: `$data = json_decode($data_json, TRUE);`

`$new_data = json_encode($data["results"]);` and all I did above is show the snippet corresponding to 'results' in the original json

Comment: The original json is exactly 999 chars long, is it accidental ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing it but you can correct it by applying the [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function to the **after** version. This will change things such as `&lt;` or `&quot;` back to their original form.

Depending on how it affects your quoting, there are a few flags you can pass it as well to get the result you need.

- ENT_COMPAT:   Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone.
- ENT_QUOTES:   Will convert both double and single quotes.
- ENT_NOQUOTES:     Will leave both double and single quotes unconverted.

**[EDIT]**

Run your broken JSON through this function:

```
function fixDoubleQuotedJSON($broken_json)
{
   return str_replace('"','\\"',$broken_json);
}
```

Comment: so actually it's the other way around... the tool i use accepts the encoded HTML and rejects the decoded. does JSON require encoded HTML or is this tool just lame?

Comment: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter this tool also says the after version is bad, on that same line.

Comment: No, JSON doesn't have to have htmlentities() applied. Although, to avoid problems, quotes should be escaped. There is a known problem with double quotes being escaped by json_encode() and then not being able to be read by jQuery's .parseJSON() but there are workarounds if you google for them.

Comment: so why do both of those json viewers complain on that line?

Comment: oh, nevermind, i see why you gave me the stuff on quotes now :)

Comment: Running your **after** JSON through that tool shows that you have too many double quotes. The ones inside the url should be escaped. Here's a related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949604/json-parse-error-with-double-quotes

Comment: right, but the issue is that either decode or encode is making the html special characters into quotes again. would be nice if they just left the special chars alone.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepad.org/DMkAS2iR

They seem to be equal, except at an unexcepted place:

```
before: "id":181554251733020673,"id_str"
after:  "id":181554251733020000,"id_str"
```

Those id's won't really match after "lossless" json transforms, and `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option is supported from PHP 5.4.

Codepad's php version is 5.2.5 by the way;

Comment: i wonder if it has to do with the version, mine is 5.2.17, and either the decode or encode ruins the special HTML characters and makes them into quotes again, which is breaking it.

Comment: also I just confirmed that it's the encode that screws it up. if i echo right after the decode, the string matches the original.